# Returning to an activity after surfaceview/thread has crashed :s

Tags: android, multithreading, crash

I have set up a program where one activity (a menu) calls another menu. This menu can then call various activities each starting a different GamePanel/thread. Pressing the arrow return button after this goes back to the menu however they have crashed and can no longer be used.

On a second point, in the first section of code, i cannot set the intent in the listener, as eclipse demands the Intent parameters are empty hence i create the pressed method, any explanations/resolutions? Thanks in advance to all!

Calling from menu:

```
private OnClickListener L1Listen = new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    L1Pressed();
}

};

public void L1Pressed()
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, L1Started.class);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

called from menu:

```
package SortItOut.sortitout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class L1Started extends Activity{

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MainGamePanelL1((this)));
 }




 protected void onDestroy()
 {
 super.onDestroy();
 }

 protected void onStop()
 {
 super.onStop();    
 }

}
```

Panel constructor (implements SurfaceHolder.callback)

```
public MainGamePanelL1(Context context){
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    thread = new MainThreadL1(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
```

Thread

```
package SortItOut.sortitout;


import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThreadL1 extends Thread {

private boolean running;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceholder;
private MainGamePanelL1 gamepanel;
int y;


public void setRunning(boolean running)
{
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThreadL1(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, MainGamePanelL1 mainGamePanelL1)
{
this.surfaceholder = surfaceholder;
this.gamepanel = mainGamePanelL1;
}


public void run()
{
    Canvas canvas;
    while(running)
    {
        canvas = null;
        try{
        canvas = this.surfaceholder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized(surfaceholder)
        {
            gamepanel.Check();
            this.gamepanel.onDraw(canvas);

        }

        }finally
        {

            if(canvas != null)
            {
                surfaceholder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }

    }
}




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crash is happening because you are performing display operations such as `onDraw()` from your background thread.  All operations on your Surfaces and Views must be done from the main UI thread.

That means you must provide some sort of mechanism so that your background threads can tell the main thread when and what to draw. One way to do this is with the Android `Handler` class, which is designed to allow you to communicate between threads.  You can use `Handler`, for example, to send a `Runnable` object to the main UI thread, which then executes it along with other asynchronous events.

Another way is to use the Android `ASyncTask` class, which wraps up a background task and provides `onProgressUpdate()` and `onPostExecute()` methods you can override. Both methods are always called on the main UI thread.

**EDIT:** There are two more ways you can force UI updates to happen on the main thread:

1) Activity has an API call `runOnUiThread()` that you can call from a background thread.  The Runnable you pass to it will be invoked on the main thread:

```
BillingActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        BillingActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

2) View has a `post()` method that similarly will queue a Runnable to be run on the UI thread in the immediate future:

```
mView.post( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mView.doSomethingOrOther();
    }
});
```

Regardless of how you do it, all View manipulation must be done on the main thread.

Comment: So would it be easier just to move onDraw etc into the thread?

Comment: All UI-related activity must be invoked from the main thread.

Comment: is this the actual code or the call? And what is considered UI-related activity?

Comment: In your code example, surfaceholder and gamepanel are both subclasses of View.  All calls your code makes to those objects must be performed on the main thread of your app.

Comment: Yes.  See the edits I made to the post, with some more suggestions on how you might go about this.  Basically, for efficiency reasons, Android does not make its UI classes thread-safe.

Comment: Hey, i have refined the code to a point where nothing is called whatsoever and it is simply a surface view calling a thread, and the crash still happens, any ideas?

Comment: Can you update the code example, so we can have a look at it?

Comment: No worries it's all sorted now, thanks for all the tips and advice.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out, sorry I couldn't be more helpful.